# Pi 3 unable to resolve host address

Tags: dns

I have recently been trying to use the Pi 3 to make a automatic seedbed with sickrage and transmission by following guides on htpcguides.com. Right now, my Pi3 is unable to resolve host addresses to sites like google.com.

I have tried adding

> dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 127.0.0.1

to my /etc/network/interfaces file but it does not seem to work

I have also tried editing /etc/resolv.conf but I understand from googling that it regenerates upon reboot.

Any help/advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try adding an 's' to dns-nameserver? 'dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4'

Comment: can you pls post the whole content of /etc/network/interfaces because i also have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /etc/network/interfaces the configuration option for dns servers is `dns-nameservers` with an **s**, as opposed to `dns-nameserver` singular. Correcting the typo solved the problem.